# Syntax error in SQL query unable to understand

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-insert

I'm getting a syntax error:
Syntax error near 17:38

```
insert into tbl_otp('mobile', 'otp', 'exp') values (9932111111, 333333, 2019-04-09 17:38:34)
```

Comment: try wrapping the values with inverted commas ""

Comment: Datetime not enclosed in single quotes

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes denote string literals, so you shouldn't use them for column names. You should, however, surround the date literal with quotes:

```
insert into
tbl_otp(mobile, otp, exp) -- no quotes
values (9932111111, 333333, '2019-04-09 17:38:34') -- quotes
```

Comment: You should quote column names with backticks not just leave them open. It's a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tbl_otp(`mobile`, `otp`, `exp`) 
values ('9932111111', '333333', '2019-04-09 17:38:34')
```

Need to backquote your column names and single-quote your values, though the latter is just to be safe.

Comment: You mean "former"

Comment: column names are not reseved words, no need for backticks

Comment: I edited to format the code with 4-space indentation, so the backticks would be more clearly visible.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Until one day they are. It doesn't hurt. Use backticks. Good habit.

Comment: I once upgraded our systems past [MySQL 5.6.2, which made `PARTITION` a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-6-detailed-P), to find that our codebase had a query without backticks around field names where one of the field names was `"partition"`. We had to push a new build to literally everybody, for a two character fix that should never have been necessary in the first place. Wasn't nice!

Answer (score 0):

put the date value in quotes and remove quotes from column names:

`insert into tbl_otp(mobile, otp, exp) values (9932111111, 333333, '2019-04-09 17:38:34')`

Comment: fixed the column names to remove the single quotes